# Magento collection filters

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I have bought a template from themeforest and I've noticed the entries in hot-sale tab stop showing a day before the `special_to_date` attribute is set ( meanwhile the general product listing is correct , and shows products on sale including the last day of campaign ).

So if we set a campain from 25th to 27th august, the hot-sale tab is empty ( today ) but the products are still on sale on general listings ( as they should ).

So I've looked into the template code and found this:

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate),
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
            array('attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
            )
      )
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc')
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->addStoreFilter();
```

Now, I'm not that good of a programmer with Magento.. and I don't really understand these `addAttributeToFilter` but my best bet is that this is exclusive ( regarding the campaign ending date ):

```
->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
```

So, if you can shed some light on this, please do. I only guess with my little knowledge this would be the problem which doesn't collect produdcts in their `last day` of `special_to_date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `$todayDate` returns the full date AND time (e.g `2015-08-27 09:30:15`), but in the database the date is saved without a time (e.g `2015-08-27 00:00:00`). So the query is inclusive but it fails because the `special_to_date` is not greater or equal to `$todayDate`.

Change the first line to:

```
 $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
```

It should fix your issue.